# How can I multiply a matrix 4x4 by a vector 4x1 to get 4x1 using numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How can I multiply a matrix 4x4 by a vector 4x1 to get 4x1 using numpy?

**Example:**

Ax=b

Matrix A:

```
|   2    |    2   |   1   |   4   |
|   1    |   -3   |   2   |   3   |
|  -1    |    1   |  -1   |  -1   |
|   1    |   -1   |   1   |   2   |
```

Vector x:

```
|   1   |
|   0   |
|  -1   |
|   1   |
```

And get b:

```
|   5   |
|   2   |
|  -1   |
|   2   |
```

I've tried `A*x`.

I got a matrix 4x4 insted of a 4x1

Comment: Try `A @ x`, this is the correct operator for matrix multiplication.

Comment: As an aside, in the future, don't provide your own ad hoc representation of your data - you are using numpy, provide **code to create the appropriate example numpy arrays**.